# Node-amqp and socket.io strange behaviour

Tags: node.js, socket.io, rabbitmq, amqp

I m actually trying to implement the pub/sub pattern using node-amqp (https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp).

I have some problems to implement it.

**What I need :**

- Publish message from a user
- Broadcast it to others user
- Sending the message to offline users that will consume it the next time they'll be connected

**What I've actually :**

```
(function () {

    var amqp = require('amqp');

    var connection = amqp.createConnection({ host: 'http://127.0.0.1:5672/' });
    var app = require('express')();
    var server = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    server.listen(8888);

// Wait for connection to become established.


    connection.on('ready', function () {

        var sendMessage = function (queue, msg) {
            connection.publish(queue, JSON.stringify(msg));
        }


        io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

            socket.on('message', function (msg) {
                sendMessage('my-queue', msg);
            });

            connection.queue('my-queue', {autoDelete: false}, function (q) {
                q.bind('#');

                q.subscribe(function (message) {
                    socket.broadcast.emit('news',message);
                });
            });

        });
    });
})()
```

- On the index.html page, I connect to the socket server
- I have a button that send a message
- I open two different browser on the index page, and my users are both connected
- If I send a message to the server, it send it to the other users
- If I send a second message to the server, it send the message to the user that sent the message.

It's switching, every pair message (because I have two users), the other users get the message, if it's an impair message, the current user sending the message receive the message.
What is this behaviour ?

Can you help me correcting my code to implement my needs a good way ?

NB : I use RabbitMQ with standard config on a windows 7 x64 computer

EDIT : I made a solution and every consumer can get the message with :

```
(function () {

    var amqp = require('amqp');

    var connection = amqp.createConnection({ host: 'http://127.0.0.1:5672/' });
    var app = require('express')();
    var server = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    server.listen(8888);

// Wait for connection to become established.


    connection.on('ready', function () {


        connection.exchange('logs', {type: 'fanout', autoDelete: false}, function (exchange) {

            var sendMessage = function (queue, msg) {
                exchange.publish(queue, JSON.stringify(msg));
            }

            io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

                socket.on('message', function (msg) {
                    sendMessage('', msg);
                });

                connection.queue(socket.id, {exclusive: true}, function (q) {
                    q.bind('logs', '');

                    q.subscribe(function (message) {
                        socket.emit('news', message);
                    });
                });

            });
        });
    });
})()
```

My last problem is that I cant manage offline messages now... Any solutions ? (bounty end tomorrow :-/)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is RabbitMQ will send each message to a single user on purpose. That user acknowledges that it received the message ([amqp does this for you automatically](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp#queuesubscribeoptions-listener)) and then the work is done as far as RabbitMQ is concerned, so it deletes the message.

The reason your users take turns receiving a message is that RabbitMQ tries to spread to load of incoming messages evenly over users.

Your question has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620976/rabbitmq-amqp-single-queue-multiple-consumers-for-same-message). Check it out for a solution to your problem!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create separate queues for each of the consumers (in your case - users), and route messages to all of them from exchange. That way, when you publish a message, it will be placed in all users' queues, from which each of them will be able to consume it independently.

You have this:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html

And you need this:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got a problem now concerning the offline data... Could you help me ? I edited my post