# Stomp Websocket with Fanout Exchange

Tags: java, spring, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp

I'm using RabbitMQ and Spring Websockets for messages to be displayed on a webpage via STOMP. I'd like each web page to receive all messages sent to the exchange (fanout).

Messages are currently received on the webpage however the behaviour is like a queue (rather than fanout) in that if 2 web pages are open and 10 messages are added to the exchange then each web page receives 5 messages.

Does anyone know what config needs to be changed to use the fanout exchange?

**Javascript**

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/messaging-example/portfolio/websocket");
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

var headers = {};
var connectCallback = function(frame) {
    stompClient.subscribe("/queue/testQueue", function(message) {
        document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + message + "</p>";
    }, { });
};
var errorCallback = function(frame) {
    console.log("Connection Error"); 
};
stompClient.connect(headers, connectCallback, errorCallback);
```

**Spring**

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/portfolio">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:stomp-broker-relay 
        relay-host="x.x.x.x"
        relay-port="61613"
        system-login="user1" 
        system-passcode="password"
        client-login="user1" 
        client-passcode="password"
        prefix="/queue"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

**RabbitMQ**

```
"queues":[  
   {  
      "name":"testQueue",
      "vhost":"/",
      "durable":true,
      "auto_delete":false,
      "arguments":{  

      }
   }
],
"exchanges":[  
   {  
      "name":"testExchange",
      "vhost":"/",
      "type":"fanout",
      "durable":true,
      "auto_delete":false,
      "internal":false,
      "arguments":{  

      }
   }
],
"bindings":[  
   {  
      "source":"testExchange",
      "vhost":"/",
      "destination":"testQueue",
      "destination_type":"queue",
      "routing_key":"",
      "arguments":{  

      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Are you listening on the same queue on both web pages? If yes, then you cannot send same messages to both the listeners. It is [load balanced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10621516/5189158)

Comment: It is the same queue definition @RaiyanMohammed but I want to connect via a fanout exchange so that all subscribers receive the same messages. I've now resolved the issue - see answer below

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer with thanks to a [post on rabbitmq user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/G8byx_sJRyg) in the Destinations section of the [rabbit mq stomp documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html).

In order to specify subscription to the queue via the fanout exchange named `testExchange` the connection string in javascript should have been `/exchange/testExchange/testQueue`. The following two changes resulted in successful subscription so that all pages received all messages:

**Spring**

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/portfolio">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:stomp-broker-relay 
        relay-host="x.x.x.x"
        relay-port="61613"
        system-login="user1" 
        system-passcode="password"
        client-login="user1" 
        client-passcode="password"
        prefix="/exchange"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

**Javascript**

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/messaging-example/portfolio/websocket");
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

var headers = {};
var connectCallback = function(frame) {
    stompClient.subscribe("/exchange/testExchange/testQueue", function(message) {
        document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + message + "</p>";
    }, { });
};
var errorCallback = function(frame) {
    console.log("Connection Error"); 
};
stompClient.connect(headers, connectCallback, errorCallback);
```