# AMQP (RabbitMQ) Pub/Sub with clustered Client

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, messaging, amqp

We are going to be developing a client which subscribes to an AMQP channel, but the client is going to be clustered (in Kubernetes) and we want only one of the clustered client to process the subscribed message.

For example, if we have a replica set of 3, we only want one to get the message, not all 3.

In JMS 2.0 this is possible using the shared consumers: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jms2messaging.html

```
1 message is sent to RabbitMQ Channel 1:

Consumer 1 (with 3 replicas) <----- RabbitMQ Channel 1
Consumer 2 (with 3 replicas) <----- RabbitMQ Channel 1

Only 2 messages would be processed
```

Is something similar possible with AMQP? The client will be developed either in C# or MuleSoft.

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620976) ?

Answer (score 2):

AMQP is designed for this. If you have three clients consuming from the *same queue*, RabbitMQ will round-robin delivery of messages to them. You may also be interested in the [Single Active Consumer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#single-active-consumer) feature.

Comment: Thanks Luke, does AMQP take into account the scenario of multiple consumers with replica sets:

    1 message is sent to RabbitMQ Channel 1:
    
    Consumer 1 (with 3 replicas) ----- RabbitMQ Channel 1
    Consumer 2 (with 3 replicas) ----- RabbitMQ Channel 1
    
Only 2 messages would be processed

Updated the OP with the "diagram"

Comment: @Steve what exactly do you mean by `channel` in "1 message is sent to RabbitMQ Channel 1:". Channels are transport layers, you send messages to either exchanges or queues.

Comment: @zerkms, as you can tell I'm not a Rabbit MQ person. I've used ActiveMQ classic with topics and queues. Rabbit MQ/AMQP endpoint is from a 3rd party vendor. If they use an exchange will that send the message to all consumers even the ones which are part of a replica set?

Comment: @Steve it depends on how they are configured, it might be delivered to all, or just one.

Comment: @zerkms - sorry are you talking about the consumers or the exchange?

Comment: @Steve https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html